# Inter record counting in pivot table - Qlikview

Tags: counter, qlikview

I have to create Qlikview pivot table like in the following example:

[image]

Column A represents the dimension of the table and the column C is the value of expression. Column B is something that I have to generate. It is not possible to do it in script since it should always start with value 1 and not depend on current selections.

How can this be implemented?
Thank you.

Comment: Please can you let me know if you have extra dimensions in your table other than `A`? Reason for asking is that otherwise QV would aggregate column `C` such that you would end up with just three rows in your table.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your interest, yes additional dimension column exists in the table which will be unique key for column C.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your source data you can use a Calculated Dimension to achieve what you require. In order to have the dimension values repeated in each row, you will need to use a Straight Table chart instead of a Pivot Table chart.

If you wish to have a dimension containing the occurrence of the dimension value in A repeated for more than one row, there is no easy way to do this without using displaying your other additional dimension that uniquely identifies the data in column `C`.

In this case, you can then use the following expression as a calculated dimension:

```
=aggr(mod(RowNo(TOTAL)-1,Count(DISTINCT TOTAL A))+1,A)
```

This then results in the following table (the `ID` column is your additional identifier column):

[image: Example of table after adding the calculated dimension]